# How to search for a specific word in Azure DevOps repository

Tags: azure-devops

I need to find the database name in an Azure DevOps repository which has multiple .net projects.

Comment: You can use [Code Search Results REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/search/code-search-results/fetch-code-search-results?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) to search fo a specific word in DevOps Repo.

Answer (score 0):

To search in the azure DevOps repo, you can use [Code Search](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-code-search)

> As your codebase expands and is divided across multiple projects and
> repositories, finding what you need becomes increasingly difficult. To
> maximize cross-team collaboration and code sharing, you need a
> solution that can quickly and efficiently locate relevant information
> across all of your projects.
>
> From discovering examples of an API's implementation, browsing its
> definition, to searching for error text, Code Search delivers a
> one-stop solution for all your code exploration and troubleshooting
> needs.